# Need to custom format a ruby date object?

Tags: ruby

how do I format a ruby date as the following?
sep14.2016

It looks like the format is 3 characters of month followed by 2 characters of day with a period and a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = Date.parse('14 September 2016')
```

to get your date object.

```
d.strftime('%b%d.%Y') #=> Sep14.2016
```

This will format your date like you wanted. Keep in mind `d` is not modified, so it is still a Date object. You need to assign the result of the `strftime` method to any variable.

You can use the `downcase` method to remove any capitalization.

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
Date.new(2016,9,14).strftime('%b%d.%Y')
```

Comment: Also `Date.today` if you want today's date.